# "campaing_id" is not a symbol error when using mail chimp api with gibbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, gibbon

*Context:* 
I have a rails application. I have a form where users can enter their email list to be a part of the news letter.
I am using mail chimp and gibbon gem for rails.
I can successfully add new subscribers to a list using the gibbon api
I can successfully create a new campaign as shown in the code below. 
In my gem file :
gem 'gibbon', git: 'git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git'
For testing out the functionality, I invoke the create action in CampaignsController(code below).
The campaign is created successfully and I get the result back from the api, but in the next step the app crashes with the following error message :

*Problem:*
TypeError in CampaignsController#create
["xyz"] is not a symbol where xyz is the campaign_id of the newly created campaign.

*Code:*
    In CampaignsController

```
def create
    mailchimp = Gibbon::API.new(Rails.application.secrets.mailchimp_api_key)
    new_campaign = mailchimp.campaigns.create({:type=>"plaintext",
      :options=>
          {:list_id=>"abcdefgh",
          :subject=>"Hello World",:from_email => "xyz@gmail.com",
          :from_name => "abc",:to_name =>"Programmer"},  

          :content => 
          {:text => "Hello remote programmers I hope you find this mail."}        
      })

    cid = new_campaign["id"]
    mailchimp.campaigns.send(cid)
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `mailchimp.campaigns.send` is looking for a hash of options, not just an id.

From their [specs](https://github.com/amro/gibbon/blob/c6abc4cb837256bc0453500bfaef950e2f24130d/spec/gibbon/gibbon_spec.rb#L210):

```
expect(@gibbon.campaigns.send({"cid" => "1234567"})).to eq({"cid" => "1234567"})
```

Comment: Is it possible to send merge variables in this send method?